# Parsing JSON with Scala lift

Tags: json, scala, lift

I am trying to parse a json string with special characters in its attributes names (dots).

This is what I'm trying:

```
//Json parser objects
case class SolrDoc(`rdf.about`:String, `dc.title`:List[String],
                   `dc.creator`:List[String], `dc.dateCopyrighted`:List[Int],
                   `dc.publisher`:List[String], `dc.type` :String)
case class SolrResponse(numFound:String, start:String, docs: List[SolrDoc])

val req = url("http://localhost:8983/solr/select") <<? Map("q" -> q)
var search_result = http(req ># { json => (json \ "response") })

var response = search_result.extract[SolrResponse]
```

Even though my json string contains values for all the fields this is the error I'm getting:

```
Message: net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for docs
No usable value for rdf$u002Eabout
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the dot on the names but so far I did not manage to make it work.

Thanks!

These is an extract from my LiftProject.scala file :

```
"net.databinder" % "dispatch-http_2.8.1" % "0.8.6",
"net.databinder" % "dispatch-http-json_2.8.1" % "0.8.6",
"net.databinder" % "dispatch-lift-json_2.8.1" % "0.8.6"
```

Comment: Databinder pulls and older version of lift json, there is a thread about it on the lift mailing list, I cannot find it now but will post the link later today.

Comment: Try this http://osdir.com/ml/liftweb/2011-10/msg00806.html

Answer (score 2):

Dots in names should not be a problem. This is with lift-json-2.4-M4

```
scala> val json = """ {"first.name":"joe"} """
scala> parse(json).extract[Person]
res0: Person = Person(joe)
```

Where

```
case class Person(`first.name`: String)
```

Comment: could it be related to dispatch.liftjson.Js._?  I'm calling solr using dispatch library (http(req ># { json => (json \ "response") })) and then processing the result as I posted earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think dispatch.liftjson.Js should not be a problem. There was a bug related to symbolic field names in some older version of Lift JSON. My guess is that you are using that older version?

Comment: this is the version I'm using :                                                         "net.databinder" % "dispatch-http_2.8.1" % "0.8.6",
    "net.databinder" % "dispatch-http-json_2.8.1" % "0.8.6",
    "net.databinder" % "dispatch-lift-json_2.8.1" % "0.8.6"
The latest, I think.

Comment: Just edited my original question to incorporate the latest information.